# Touchpad only starts working after suspend on Ubuntu 16.04 of Asus laptop

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, asus, elantech

I have a weird problem with my ASUS K556UB laptop.
When I start the computer, the touchpad doesn't work, it is shown in
`xinput` output and in `/proc/bus/input/devices`.

Here's the weird part: it starts working when I wake the computer from suspend. So the driver is working. Anyone got any idea how I could get it working without suspending and waking?
Here are the outputs from `xinput`, `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` and `synclient`, respectively:

- http://pastebin.com/AJPxrjPk
- http://pastebin.com/0x30uKBG
- http://pastebin.com/R0CgY2dN

As you can see, it's an Elantech touchpad, I've had a few laptops with Elantech touchpads and they worked perfectly.
A mouse is also in the outputs, I had to attach it to use the computer. It had no effect on the touchpad.

Hardware: Asus laptop K556UB
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Comment: Hi, this is known issue in Asus-laptops of Elantech touchpads. Please, see the other thread. Please, let me know if you can solve the issue with it. - - I went through all your pastes and it seems to be about the same issue.

Comment: I've tried all the answers from that link, none of them worked

Comment: Can you please show your work process in the body for your attempts. This can exclude mistakes and confirm us about your attempts.