# FocalTech Touchpad works only after suspension in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, suspend, touchpad

My pc is an Asus X550LD.
Here `xinput` results:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FocalTechPS/2 FocalTech FocalTech Touchpad    id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I readed this: 
[Touchpad only starts working after suspend on Ubuntu 16.04 of Asus laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/810694/touchpad-only-starts-working-after-suspend-on-ubuntu-16-04-of-asus-laptop)
but didn't solve.

Comment: This issue is specific to some laptop model and the problem is in the firmware. You did not even mention what is the laptop, like it does not work everywhere. I do not have this problem at all.

Comment: You can probably fix it by `i8042.reset` boot parameter.

Comment: @Pilot6 the laptop is a Asus-F550L

Comment: @Pilot6 setting i8042.reset as boot parameter didn't work

Comment: Try `i8042.noloop=1` it is hard to tell what is the problem with the laptop firmware.

Comment: @PIlot6 it didn't solve...

Comment: Do you run `sudo update-grub` after you add parameters?

Comment: @Pilot6 yes of course

Comment: Is the touchpad detected after a boot?

Comment: nope  it isn't @Pilot6

Comment: I suggest filing a bug report to Launchpad. Do a fresh boot and report it using `ubuntu-bug linux`. Then describe that it is detected after a suspend. There will be some debug information.

Comment: And also try `i8042.nomux=1` option too. Some laptops do not detect serio devices without this option.

Comment: This also may work `i8042.kbdreset=1`. On some laptops it helps to detect the touchpad.

Comment: @Pilot6 didn't work.After that ubuntu stop booting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was that touchpad (I don't know why) was disabled in bios setting. I don't know why in ubuntu worked after suspension even if was disabled. I apologize with @Pilot6 and  @Sandeep Neupane to have wasted their time.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution, but it might be only a workaround.Let me know if it works.

`sudo modprobe -r psmouse
 sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`

Comment: It didn't work. If I do this even after suspension didn't work. To make it work I have to restart an then re-suspend again